# Apache synapse: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/synapse/task/Task

Tags: apache-synapse

I deployed a simple custom task. At startup, synapse does find the class with my custom task but it cannot find it's own Task interface. Strange. The Task interface is defined in synapse-tasks-2.1.0.jar and I verified the jar is included in synapse classpath.

1. My task:

   ```
   package com.mytest.synapse;
   import org.apache.synapse.task.Task;
   public class MyTask implements Task {
     @Override
     public void execute() {
       System.out.println("my task in action");
     }
   }
   ```
2. Synapse config file:

   ```
   <definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
       <task class="com.mytest.synapse.MyTask" name="Task1">
           <trigger interval="5"/>
       </task>
   </definitions>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the custom jars are to be placed in lib, not in lib/endorsed. Per instructions I got from a synapse developer I moved my custom from lib/endorsed to lib and it worked.